# Evenness of Fourier coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z})$ and let $F(n)$ denote its Fourier coefficients $$F(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx$$ I want to prove that $f$ is even if and only if $F(n)=F(-n)$ for all $n$.

Suppose $f$ is even. Then I have to prove $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{-inx}dx=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{inx}dx$. This is true because the value on the left-hand side at $a$ is $f(a)e^{-ina}$, while the value of the right-hand side at $-a$ is $f(-a)e^{-ina}=f(a)e^{-ina}$.

What about the converse? Suppose $F(n)=F(-n)$ for all $n$. How can I show that $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x$?

Comment: How about making a change of variables and applying an inverse Fourier transform?

Comment: @Riemann1337 Are there more elementary ways than that? (i.e. without making the inverse Fourier transform)

Comment: Maybe there is a way to argue it by just subtracting the integrals, but I am not sure;  using the inverse Fourier transform seems to be the most straightforward way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing variables, we have 
$$
F(n)=F(-n)\rightarrow \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) e^{inx}dx=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) e^{-inx}dx
=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(-x) e^{inx}dx, 
$$
so
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi[f(x)-f(-x)]e^{inx}dx = 0.
$$
If $\mathcal{F}$ denotes the Fourier transform, then we have that 
$$
0=\mathcal{F}[f(x)-f(-x)]\rightarrow\mathcal{F}[f(x)] = \mathcal{F}[f(-x)].
$$
Applying the inverse Fourier transform should give the result.